# Prevent search engines indexing pages with 3 or more forwarslashes in their paths

Tags: seo, search-engine, robots.txt

How can I prevent search engines indexing pages with 3 or more  forwarslashes in their paths?
for example:

```
www.example.com/about.html ->ok
www.example.com/1/2/3/4/5/test.html -> no index!!!
```

How should I write the robots.txt? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /*/*/*/*
```

Although I'm not sure all bots support the `*`.